# Why $x^2+3x^4+\omicron(x^4)=\omicron(x^3)$is false?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Why $x^2+3x^4+\omicron(x^4)=\omicron(x^3)$is false for $x\to 0$?

I know that:
A. $-\omicron(f)=\omicron(f)$
B. $\omicron(f)+\omicron(f)=\omicron(f)$
C. If g is a function $g*\omicron(f)=\omicron(gf)$
C2. if g is costant$g*\omicron(f)=\omicron(gf)=\omicron(f)$
D. $\omicron(f)^n=\omicron(f^n)$
E. $\omicron(f+\omicron(f))=\omicron(f)$

From C I try to write $\omicron(x^4)=x^4\omicron(1)$ but I don't know what my next move is.

Comment: $x^2  \ne o(x^3 )$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: $x^2$ is not $o(x^3)$ (as $x\to 0$).

Answer (score 1):

If
$$x^2+3x^4+\omicron(x^4)=\omicron(x^3)$$ then

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2+3x^4+\epsilon(x)x^4}{x^3} = 0$$

where $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \epsilon(x) =0$.

And this is not the case as

$$\frac{x^2}{x^3}$$ is not bounded around zero.

Comment: What is $\epsilon(x)x^4$? It’s equal to $\omicron(1)x^4$?

Comment: This is by definition of $\omicron$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hunderstand that the greater the power of x^n is, the closer you are from zero. Personnaly I prefer O(x) rather than o(x), because i find it easyer to hunderstand, and to control. However, forget about all the rules of o(x), and try to focus on what they mean. Here x^4 IS a o(x^3). And it's the same with o(x^4). So your expression is equivalent x^2+o(x^3)=o(x^3). Wich is equivalent to x^2=o(x3). It can't be true, because x^2 is very big compare with o(x^3).

Comment: therefore in this exercise I can “eat” everything that is bigger than the quantity to the right and after I can “delete” every equivalent sum $\omicron(.)$ to apply the definition?